# Request to Join Projects - Database schema recommendations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, schema

my app has the following models:

```
User
Projects
Permissions (project_id, user_id, role_id)
```

role_id of 1 equals admin

I want to create a way for user's to request to join a project. That request would be available to the project admin to Approve or "Not Now", with Not Now that would prevent the user from continuing to request to join, just like on Facebook.

Any schema recommendations oh the table/fields to build this correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

New model `Request` with a `user_id` and `project_id` and on approval the real `Permission` is written, whereas on *"Not Now"* the request is deleted.

Some admin page just shows the outstanding requests, and if you wish user and/or project filters.